# Как правильно сделать сериализацию в nestjs?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

Я получаю данные из монги через nestjs. Допустим хочу получить всех пользователей
Вот контролле, который обрабатывает эндпоинт

```
@Get('/getAll')
  async getAll() {
    return this.userService.getAll();
  }
```

Вот сервис который получает данные из монги с помощью монгуса

```
async getAll(): Promise<User[]> {
    try {
      return await this.userModel.find().exec();
    } catch (error) {
      throw new BadRequestException('Users not found');
    }
  }
```

Вот объект одного пользователя в ответе:

```
{
    
    "lastname": "Gabbana",
    "_id": "5f782ace2cdfcd297c373ba6",
    "name": "Dolce",        
    "password": "$2b$10$DSomsGAk4FuXUH6Knnmdz.9L2DWlFTfH.VOIM8VKYlDroOwKeh7kW",
    "__v": 0
 }
```

Все работает как нужно. Но я хочу сделать сериализацию данных. В документации nestjs рекомендуют использовать декоратор **@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)** для контроллера. А в модели нужно над полем которое нужно исключать при сериализации нужно применить декоратор **@Exclude()** 
То есть вот так:

```
@Schema()
export class User extends Document {
  @Prop()
  name: string;

  @Prop({ default: '' })
  lastname: string;
  
  @Exclude()
  @Prop()
  password: string;
}

export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);
```

Но проблема в том, что теперь я получаю очень большой объект по каждому  пользователю, в котором масса ненужной мне информации и при этом при всем, поле пароля не исключено из ответа, то есть и сериализация не прошла и ответ получается не тем.

```
{
    "$__": {
      "strictMode": true,
      "selected": {},
      "getters": {},
      "_id": {
        "_bsontype": "ObjectID",
        "id": {
          "type": "Buffer",
          "data": [
            95,
            120,
            42,
            206,
            44,
            223,
            205,
            41,
            124,
            55,
            59,
            166
          ]
        }
      },
      "wasPopulated": false,
      "activePaths": {
        "paths": {
          "role": "init",
          "registerAt": "init",
          "status": "init",
          "lastname": "init",
          "_id": "init",
          "name": "init",
          "email": "init",
          "phone": "init",
          "password": "init",
          "__v": "init"
        },
        "states": {
          "ignore": {},
          "default": {},
          "init": {
            "_id": true,
            "role": true,
            "registerAt": true,
            "status": true,
            "lastname": true,
            "name": true,
            "email": true,
            "phone": true,
            "password": true,
            "__v": true
          },
          "modify": {},
          "require": {}
        },
        "stateNames": [
          "require",
          "modify",
          "init",
          "default",
          "ignore"
        ]
      },
      "pathsToScopes": {},
      "cachedRequired": {},
      "session": null,
      "$setCalled": [],
      "emitter": {
        "_events": {},
        "_eventsCount": 0,
        "_maxListeners": 0
      },
      "$options": {
        "skipId": true,
        "isNew": false,
        "willInit": true,
        "defaults": true
      }
    },
    "isNew": false,
    "$locals": {},
    "$op": null,
    "_doc": {     
      
      "lastname": "Gabbana",
      "_id": {
        "_bsontype": "ObjectID",
        "id": {
          "type": "Buffer",
          "data": [
            95,
            120,
            42,
            206,
            44,
            223,
            205,
            41,
            124,
            55,
            59,
            166
          ]
        }
      },
      "name": "Dolce",
      
      
      "password": "$2b$10$DSomsGAk4FuXUH6Knnmdz.9L2DWlFTfH.VOIM8VKYlDroOwKeh7kW",
      "__v": 0
    },
    "$init": true
  }
```

Вот такой объект приходит для каждого юзера. В документации такого не происходит и в гугле я такого не нашел, везде приходит нормальный ответ. Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Попробуйте `return await this.userModel.find().exec().toObject()`.

Comment: Не пропускает TypeScript - там должен вернутся массив юзеров, в котором нет свойства toObject(), я так понимаю что он это берет из модели, потому что я явно не указываю что вернется

Comment: А, ну да, `toObject()` - это для одного элемента. Можно попробовать через `map` прогнать. А ещё можно же сразу при запросе к монге исключить ненужные поля.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Получилось так return await (await this.userModel.find().exec()).map(item =>
        item.toObject(),
      ); Но это как-то костыльно помоему=( В доках такого нет и в других примерах в инете

Comment: Поспешил. Работает то оно в том виде, что объект теперь нужного вида, но сериализация не проходит, в ответе пароль. Я делал сериализацию по-другому, варианты есть как сделать, но хочется сделать как в документации это сделано, через интерцептор

Comment: Ну, дальше я не помощник, что такое nestjs и как оно работает - представления не имею. :(